# Ole DB statement runs in Access but not in Visual Studios

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I have the following statement and it returns my desired result in Access however in Visual Studio, I receive an error saying "; expected", what could be the problem?

```
var query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM usersTable WHERE (((usersTable.[uDateCreated]) Between DateAdd("d",-2,Now()) And Now()))";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ole DB Select Count Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636534/ole-db-select-count-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes inside your string:

```
" .. Between DateAdd(\"d\",-2 .. "
                     ^  ^ escape the quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a quotation mark in your query, which is ending the string.  Use apostrophes around `d` instead:

```
var query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM usersTable WHERE (((usersTable.[uDateCreated]) " & _
    "Between DateAdd('d',-2,Now()) And Now()))"
```

Specifically:

```
DateAdd('d',-2,Now())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have " (quotes) in your string without escaping them. I donut know which language you are using, but for many you escape with \ (backslash), then your string would read *DateAdd(\"d\",*